# How do I add a new table to my extension?

Tags: custom-fields, database, gsoc

I have added tables to my database by writing SQL commands in a sql folder as specified in the given link. 
[Add a database upgrader / Installer / uninstaller](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addadatabaseupgrader/Installer/uninstaller).

What I am exactly looking for is a method to access these tables, do I need to write direct SQL for adding records to the table or I should create corresponding DAO and BAO to access the table.

How to create DAO and BAO for a given table in an extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did for the sepa extension is a bit of a hack, but worked ok:

write the xml schema files, as you have them on the (development version) core and run xml/phpGencode.php to generate the dao, that you then copy into the extension folders and voila, you got the tables ready to use (for a few more lines, you got the api files, worthwhile IMO)

The process is now detailed in our [developer book](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity)

Comment: This means BAO is still need to be written manually. I found a standard guideline, which needs to be followed, but I am assuming this needs to be done manually.

Comment: Detailed steps for this process are now documented here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity

Comment: What is development version; I have installed civicrm in my pc with Drupal but could not see the XML folder in civicrm root directory

Comment: @Xavier: how to get the development version; In my pc I installed civicrm with drupla 7; No XML folder or xml/phpGencode.php

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi, start a new question ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `civix generate:entity`.  It's marked as "EXPERIMENTAL AND INCOMPLETE" on my copy of civix - though my version might be old.  Either way, it should point you in the right direction.

UPDATE: While you should still run `civix generate:entity`, at the time of this writing, it will create a BAO but NOT a DAO file for you.  Use Xavier's technique (the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I tend to create the file in sql and then create a DAO in my extension with the few functions that are required. Check https://github.com/CiviCooP/no.maf.oppgavexml/blob/master/CRM/Oppgavexml/DAO/Oppgave.php for an example of a DAO I have copied and pasted into my extension for a table I created in the Upgrade class using

```
$this->executeSqlFile('sql/create_civicrm_oppgave.sql');
```