# Difficulties generating an entity's DAO and SQL for a new extension

Tags: mysql, civicrm-entity, core, civix

I have been trying to generate DAO and SQL files for an entity I created with `civix generate:entity ...` according to the [documentation ("Add a new entity" - 4.d.)](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity).

Using the latest civicrm-core clone (latest commit [e637260](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/e637260340bde2c4426b520a705ec86465ef7015)) I:

1. ran `composer install` on the root (civiroot);
2. verified that the vendor folder has the same packages that come along with, for example, CiviCRM 4.7.20 for Drupal 7.x (`sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor`);
3. copied the new entity's schema to the `xml/schema` folder;
4. altered the `Schema.xml` itself to include this entity.

However, after running `bash bin/setup.sh -g` or `php xml/GenCode.php` this comes up:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Log.php'

I.e. `<root>/CRM/Core/Config.php` is expecting:

```
require_once 'Log.php';
require_once 'Mail.php';
```

I searched for a while and I could not find these files, so I just thought of trying it out without these lines from `Config.php`, but once I rerun I got:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant *PEAR_ERROR_CALLBACK* - assumed 'PEAR_ERROR_CALLBACK' in `<root>/CRM/Core/TemporaryErrorScope.php` on line 49
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: _PEAR_default_error_mode
>   in `<root>/CRM/Core/TemporaryErrorScope.php` on line 74
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: _PEAR_default_error_options
>   in `<root>/CRM/Core/TemporaryErrorScope.php` on line 75
>
> Warning:  require_once(**PEAR/ErrorStack.php**): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in `<root>/CRM/Core/Error.php` on line 36
>
> Fatal error:  require_once(): **Failed opening required
>   'PEAR/ErrorStack.php'** (include_path='`.:<root>:<root>/packages:<root>/vendor/tecnickcom:<root>/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:<root>/vendor/pear/pear_exception:<root>/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:<root>/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:../packages:..`')
>   in /CRM/Core/Error.php on line 36

I did find a PEAR folder but it is in `<root>/vendor/pear/pear_exception/PEAR`, without any `ErrorStack.php` file.

I also found a couple of related questions in here:

- [How to automatically generate DAO classes for my DB tables](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/how-to-automatically-generate-dao-classes-for-my-db-tables)
- [How do I add a new table to my extension?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/how-do-i-add-a-new-table-to-my-extension?rq=1)

In the last one, I understand that people seem to run the code generator without such problems.

I apologize the long question, **TLDR;**

- what am I missing? What does `GenCode.php` need in order to run properly?
- is there another way to generate DAO and SQL files for new entities?

Comment: Hi @Armfoot, did you already try to install buildkit to create a development instance (See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/).  I installed my development machine this way and the setup script works.

Comment: Thank you @Kainuk. Although the `setup.sh` script runs for me as well (in a clean core clone, without even buildkit), the generation option (`-g`) does not. I indeed added the buildkit bin folder to the relevant environment variable (PATH), but even so, the files I mentioned continue to be required. I am still considering if any of the buildkit scripts would generate these missing files...

Answer (score 1):

`civix generate:entity` is experimental and, last I checked, broken.

When I need to do this, my approach is as follows:

1. create my XML file for the new entity
2. run a helper script to generate the SQL and DAO

Have a look at the [helper files](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/tree/master/bin) in CiviVolunteer for guidance; they should work for any project with minimal modification.

Comment: `generate:entity` isn't actually broken (for me at least): it created the appropriate folder, a few PHP files and even the XML, I just needed to add more fields to it. I believe it is [mentioned as experimental and incomplete](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity) because ideally it would also generate the DAO and SQL files. I saw the helper script you linked and realized it's a short version of the core's setup.sh, calling `php GenCode.php` at the end, which also fails due to the missing files I mentioned above. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion Frank.

Answer (score 1):

`civix` is now capable of generating the SQL and DAO with: `civix generate:entity-boilerplate`.  [The civix documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity) gives more info.